# Jenkins Pipeline stage skip based on groovy variable defined in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to skip a `stage` based a groovy variable and that variable value will be calculated in another stage.

In the below example, `Validate` stage is conditionally skipped based Environment variable `VALIDATION_REQUIRED` which I will pass while building/triggering the Job. --- *This is working as expected.*

Whereas the `Build` stage always runs even though `isValidationSuccess` variable is set as `false`.
I tried changing the `when` condition expression like `{ return "${isValidationSuccess}" == true ; }`  or `{ return "${isValidationSuccess}" == 'true' ; }` but none worked.
When printing the variable it shows as 'false'

```py
def isValidationSuccess = true 
 pipeline {
    agent any
    stages(checkout) {
        // GIT checkout here
    }
    stage("Validate") {
        when {
            environment name: 'VALIDATION_REQUIRED', value: 'true'
        }
        steps {
            if(some_condition){
                isValidationSuccess = false;
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Build") {
        when {
            expression { return "${isValidationSuccess}"; }
        }
        steps {
             sh "echo isValidationSuccess:${isValidationSuccess}"
        }
    }
 }
```

1. At what phase does the `when` condition will be evaluated.
2. Is it possible to skip the stage based on the variable using `when`?
3. Based on a few SO answers, I can think of adding conditional block as below, But `when` options look clean approach. Also, the `stage view` shows nicely when that particular stage is skipped.

```py
script {
      if(isValidationSuccess){
             // Do the build
       }else {
           try {
             currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED' 
           } catch(Exception err) {
             currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
           }
           error('Build not happened')
       }
}
```

References:
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

Comment: Why do you use a `return` in the `when`? Did you try `when { expression { isValidationSuccess == true } }` ?

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, great! I will post it as answer so people can see the solution more clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
stage("Build") {
        when {
            expression { isValidationSuccess == true }
        }
        steps {
             // do stuff
        }
    }
```

`when` validates boolean values so this should be evaluate to true or false.

[Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)