# How do I skip a Jenkins stage after executing some of its steps (like the when directive)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How do I skip a Jenkins stage partway through its execution? It would be like using `when` after some steps or in the middle of a step, once the skip condition has been determined. I'm aware that I could break stages/steps down further and use a global variable to achieve this, but there seems like there should be a simpler way.

**The step should appear skipped, not failed or unstable.**

```java
stage('Builds') {
    failFast true
    parallel {
        stage('FlagA') {
            steps {
                BuildWithFlag("FlagA")
            }
        }
        stage('FlagB') {
            steps {
                BuildWithFlag("FlagB")
            }
        }
        ...

void BuildWithFlag(String flag) {
    skipCondition = false
    <setup-steps>
    if(skipCondition) {
        currentStage.result = '' // Doesn't work
        return
    }
    <build-steps>
}
```

---

Related:
[Conditional step/stage in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37690920/11402024)
[How to perform when..else in declarative pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48785761/11402024)
[Jenkins Pipeline stage skip based on groovy variable defined in pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57602609/11402024)

All of these use `when` at the start of the stage. I need to mimic it partway through a step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set the stage to `"NOT_BUILT"`. This is the status given to steps that are skipped using `when`.

E.g.

```java
if(skipCondition) {
    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'NOT_BUILT') {
        error "Skipping..." // Force an error that we will catch to set the stageResult
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: "return" actually returns control from the "step" being executed. It doesn't exit the stage.